# The logic behind saving a game state in Unity: each class in the app has to have load/save facilities?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am starting with saving states; and I grew out of playerprefs pretty quickly, now that I have a consistent amount of classes and data, for each session.

What I fail to grasp, is the basic concept of how saving works in Unity: is there some sort of mechanism that does a snapshot of your executable and classes/objects/variables, and allow you to restore it, like you would do with a OS backup, or it is based on writing every single parameter and object in a sort of customized file format, to then restore it at later time, re-creating all the objects and passing these saved parameters so you can override the default?

I am asking, since I am not sure if I have to design my classes to "allow" saving, in the case of the second scenario (saving all the parameters).

In my case, I have few managers, one player, few AI entities and a ton of NPC, and on top of that an economic simulation based on buy/sell activities from other AI based teams, related to the market of the variouos players.
In this scenario, I could probably loose count pretty easily of how many parameters I have to actually save, for every single entity.

Could you please point me to the right direction, so I can understand if I need to dive in my classes and change each one of them to include a sort of "retrieval and replacement" of every single parameter in it; or not.

Comment: "What I fail to grasp, is the basic concept of how saving works in Unity"  There is absolutely NO such concept in Unity.  Quite simply, unity very simply "have not yet addressed this issue, whatsoever".   So for better or worse, you simply have to do it absolutely yourself, in whatever way you want.

Comment: This is both depressing and positive at the same time. Knowing that there is no magic solution, and that I have to implement everything, helps a lot.

Comment: Right, now you've got it.  Be aware that Unity has a whole "Serialization" system.  But it's basically total crap.  People spend man-months screwing around with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and save your data in a file and load the data from file on resuming the session. Have a look at [this](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934) example. Notice that in the example the person did save the Game class that may contain various classes and in a result don't have to worry for each class like `character`.

Also there are couple of examples:

[Persistence - Saving and Loading Data](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/persistence-data-saving-loading)

[Unity Save Game / Level Serialization](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-save-game-level-serialization.138678/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I did check serialization, because it was in a Unity tutorial, but what they were doing was to create a class taht contain data, copy ALL the data in this class, mark this class serializable and then with standard IO, create a file and write/read on it. If this is the case, it will take me days to collect all the locations of the data that I need to save, to copy it in this "container" class; so before stabbing myself in this way, I did start to look for alternatives :) Checking the other options that you mentioned, crossing fingers.

Comment: "If this is the case, it will take me days to collect all the locations of the data that I need to save"  Totally wrong. It will take you one or two man-months of work to implement a "save game state" concept in a serious Unity project.  Note that if you want to send it up to PlayGameServices or the like, that will take another month+ of work.

Comment: My thinking is that, if there are dozen and tons of things to save now, either it should be a clear requirement in the start so things were designed like that (instead of covering each and everything and think about that) or it should now be expected as a big change. Or perhaps i am lost too.

Comment: Well, I agree with you; although I started with player prefs....it didn't look so bad when the project started, so the first thought was "we will deal with it later". Now, I have enough knowledge to understand better the "save/load" problematic, and I can deal with it before we reach the point of non-return. In my dreams, Unity would have some mechanism to ease this pain, like it does with everything else; which is why the topic was pushed back, thinking that it won't take long to implement that magic in the project. I was wrong, and glad to find it out now :)

Comment: lol sorry for the "super bad news" guys!  heh.  yeah it's a HUGE project.  It's rather like implementing "Pause" (like when the player pauses) in a game.  That is an incredibly time consuming process that basically doubles the work of a whole game.  Anyways cheers